# How to prevent my jsp application from Cross Frame Scripting?

Tags: java, jsp

I am using jsp.
I have to provide security to the application from Cross Frame Scripting. I have to ensure that all pages that gather user information prior to and during authentication are not vulnerable. The pages must prevent being encapsulated within a frameset of an unauthorized site.
Need to know more how to prevent frames from becoming encapsulated.

I have already gone through the below link but couldn't find the appropriate solution.
"https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting"

I'm expecting some demo project so that I can understand more about Cross Frame Scripting and how my application is safe from being encapsulated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 0):

Use the X-Frame-Options header with value DENY, SAMEORIGIN or ALLOW-FROM uri in your HTTP response to prevent your website being loaded in a frame.

Another method is validating your url with the source url and reload the page with your url if any cross frame scripting find.
Refer below script to do it.

```
    <script>
     window.onload = function() {
      if (window.location !== window.top.location) {
       window.top.location = window.location;
      }
     }
    </script>
```